# how to print dictionary data in the tabular form in python

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary as follows.I want to print the data in the tabular form. Now condition here is i want to print only certain data in table for an example : BIRT, NAME, and SEX. how can i do that?

```
 import sys 
 import pandas as pd     
 indi ={}
 indi =   {'@I7@': {'BIRT': '15 NOV 1925', 'FAMS': '@F2@', 'NAME': 'Rose /Campbell/',   'DEAT': '26 AUG 2009', 'SEX': 'F'}, '@I5@': {'BIRT': '15 SEP 1928', 'FAMS': '@F3@', 'NAME': 'Rosy /Huleknberg/', 'DEAT': '10 MAR 2010', 'SEX': 'F'}}
 person = pd.DataFrame(indi).T
 person.fillna(0, inplace=True)
 print(person)
```

output

```
          BIRT         DEAT        FAMC  FAMS             NAME    SEX

 @I5@   15 SEP 1928  10 MAR 2010     0  @F3@   Rosy /Huleknberg/   F

 @I7@   15 NOV 1925  26 AUG 2009     0  @F2@     Rose /Campbell/   F
```

Comment: Could you show your attempts, or anything you've tried to make it work? And also explain what you mean by "tabular form"?

Comment: show your code so far, and show what you would like your output to look like

Comment: There are a million "how do I print this dictionary" questions per day on this tag. Can you please explain why _none_ of those helped you, what you are stuck on, and what on earth "in the tabular form" means?

Comment: question edited with output

Comment: Gus Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

You can try to use something like this:

```
print(person.filter(['BIRT', 'NAME', 'SEX']))
```

Output will be:

```
             BIRT               NAME SEX
@I5@  15 SEP 1928  Rosy /Huleknberg/   F
@I7@  15 NOV 1925    Rose /Campbell/   F
```